# html5 video width is not expanding 100%

Tags: jquery, html, css

I don't know if this is possible or not.
I want to play a background video in top header section (not body background video). I have a video which is not expanding 100%.

Also I want a static banner first thing that you see when accessing the website, then transition (some kind of fade) to the background video.

https://jsfiddle.net/v6oo5eh5/1/

```
<style>
    /* The only rule that matters */
    #video-background {
        /*  making the video fullscreen  */
        position:fixed;
        /*  bottom: 0;*/
        /* min-width: 100%; 
        min-height: 100%;*/
        /*width:auto; 
        height: auto;*/
        z-index: -100;
        left:0;
        float:left;
        top:0;
        width:1920px;
    }
</style>

<video autoplay loop id="video-background" muted style="background:red; height:500px;">
    <source src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/clientevents/FIPPUK001-HMNHDF76C7D/video/Fipp_Congress_2.mp4" type="video/mp4" align="left">
</video>
```

I have no clue how can I do this. Is there any example or hint to get this done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use `video {object-fit: fill;}` to fill video beyond it's origin dimensions.

Comment: this is good. but stretches the video to fit the content box. how to avoid stretch

Answer (score 0):

You have the height set to 500px, so the width will be set in ratio to that height.  If you remove the height it will go full width, however the height will also scale too.

If you want the height fixed to 500px, you could add a container with overflow set to hidden, but you will lose some of the video.

Below is an example using jQuery for the banner fade too

```
<style>
    #video-background {
        /*  making the video fullscreen  */
        position:fixed;
        z-index: -100;
        left:0;
        float:left;
        top:0;
        width:1920px;
        height: 500px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .banner{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
        background: blue;
    }
</style>

<div id="video-background">
    <div class="banner">
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </div>
    <video autoplay loop muted style="background:red; width: 100%;">
      <source src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/clientevents/FIPPUK001-HMNHDF76C7D/video/Fipp_Congress_2.mp4" type="video/mp4" align="left">
    </video>
</div>

<script>
    $(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(".banner").fadeOut();
        }, 500);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

please check this code:-

```
<div id="video-background">
<video autoplay loop muted style="background:red; width: 100%;">
  <source src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/clientevents/FIPPUK001-HMNHDF76C7D/video/Fipp_Congress_2.mp4" type="video/mp4" align="left">
</video>
</div>
```

click here:- https://jsfiddle.net/v6oo5eh5/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
 max-width: 1920px;
 width: 100%;
 object-fit: cover;
```

You can use    `object-fit: cover;` while setting a `max-width` and a `width`

https://jsfiddle.net/v6oo5eh5/6/